# Como alterar o valor de um atributo "data" em JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um atributo `data-order` em um botão e eu quero ele seja incrementado de acordo com que eu vá adicionando novos `days` à minha lista através do clique do botão, assim terei:

```
day-1
day-2
day-3
day-4
```

... e assim por diante. Alguém sabe como eu posso incrementar esse valor em jQuery?

P.S.: O botão tem um ID único. Eu só não sei como fazer a incrementação.

EDIT: A pergunta não é sobre concatenação, mas sobre alterar o valor do `data-order`. Eu só tenho um desses atributos e quero alterar o seu valor de `day-1` para `day-2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var valor = 0;
$('#botao').on('click', function () {
    valor++;
    $(this).data('order', 'day-' + valor);
});
```

- Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Agr7p/

Fiz uma alteração no exemplo só para ficar mais fácil a ilustração.
http://jsfiddle.net/Agr7p/10/
Abraços!

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava querendo cara, vlw! o/

Comment: Se possível, crie um exemplo utilizando a ferramenta `trecho de código` aqui no SOpt. Assim, se por algum motivo der problema no código postado no JSFiddle a pergunta não deixará de ser útil.

Answer (score 6):

As demais respostas estão assumindo que você pretende usar exclusivamente o método [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) do jQuery, e parece estarem corretas, mas é bom fazer uma distinção: [os atributos `data-*` do HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) **não são a mesma coisa** que os dados armazenados pelo jQuery através do método `.data`. O jQuery armazena esses dados internamente, e isso não se reflete no elemento original. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Agr7p/4/).

Se você por alguma razão quiser atualizar o próprio elemento, não atribua usando `.data`, mas sim usando [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). A leitura também deve ser feita da mesma forma - pois o `.data` apenas coloca o primeiro valor encontrado em cache, depois não consulta mais o elemento.

```
var valor = $(this).attr('data-order').split('-')[1];
valor++;
$(this).attr('data-order', 'day-' + valor);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Agr7p/5/). Se você inspecionar o botão no browser, verá que ele de fato possui o atributo `data-order` com um valor atualizado.

Answer (score 5):

Deixo mais uma resposta ([para browsers modernos](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset)) que é usando a API do HTML5.

Na verdade não vai ser preciso jQuery para isto, pode usar-se o [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).

A API é simples:

> *Elemento.dataset.**nome***                 // para ler
>   *Elemento.dataset.**nome*** = *'novo valor'* // para atribuir

Exemplo:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#user');
var resultados = document.querySelector('#resultados');

// visualizar os campos data- 
// repare que pode verificar a existência de campos como "dateOfBirth" que não existe ainda, vai dar false
resultados.innerHTML = [el.dataset.id, el.dataset.user, !!el.dataset.dateOfBirth].join(' - '); 

el.dataset.dateOfBirth = '1960-10-03'; // settar a data.
resultados.innerHTML += ' - ' + el.dataset.dateOfBirth;
```

```html
<div id="user" data-id="1234567890" data-user="johndoe">John Doe</div>

<div id="resultados"></div>
```

Para fazer com JS puro em browsers antigos que não suportam HTML5 pode usar-se `getAttribute`/`setAttribute`.

Nota: como o [@mgibsonbr referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4006/129) o jQuery [não muda a mesma propriedade](http://jsfiddle.net/awkvzd91/) que o JavaScript puro muda!

```
$(el).data('foo', 'bar'); // seta o valor
$(el).data('foo'); // dá bar
el.dataset.foo;    // dá undefined
```

Ai, ai... `-1` para o jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

`data-*` são atributos personalizáveis de elementos HTML, ele é armazenado como  propriedade string no objeto dataset do elemento. Se você está salvando uma lista de valores nele, na realidade você está concatenando string.

Por exemplo:

```
var num = 0; // a fins de exemplo
$('#meu_botao').data('order', $('#meu_botao').data('order') + ', day-' + num++);
```

Isso pode ser adicionado ao evento de clique que vai resultar em adicionar valores ao atributo `data-order`, mas vai ficar assim:

```
'day-1, day-2, day-3' // e por ai vai, conforme for sendo adicionado
```

Você pode quebrar essa string depois em uma Array pra poder tratar os valores por exemplo:

```
$('#meu_botao').data('order').split(', '); // ["day-1", "day-2", "day-3"]
```

---

EDIT (apos melhor explicação da pergunta):

No caso de querer incrementar o valor de day-{n} contido em data, você pode usar o `String.prototype.match` pra pegar o valor existente.

```
var num = $('#meu_botao').data('order').match(/day-([0-9]*)/), num = num && + num[1] || 0;
$('#meu_botao').data('order', 'day-' + num++);
```

Dessa maneira você não vai precisar fazer cache do numero em uma variável e vai poder usar sempre o valor contido em `data-*`

Comment: Essa é uma boa resposta, mas não é exatamente o que eu estava perguntando. Perguntava sobre como alterar o valor do `data-order` de `day-1` para `day-2`.

Comment: para o atributo data use a função http://api.jquery.com/data em vez de attr ... motivo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: @DennisBraga ah, não tinha entendido direito, achei que você estava querendo uma lista ordenada, mas então a resposta do Daniel satisfaz. Só vou corrigir a questão do attr pra data, pois é ideal com jquery.

Comment: Gostei de edit feito à pergunta. Muito bom mesmo! Essa de não precisar guardar em cache o resultado, é show! :D

Comment: @DennisBraga fico feliz em poder ajudar, melhorei a sintaxe pra caso o valor data('order') venha vazio não dar erro no seu código. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

os atributos data podem ser mudados com o metodo data do proprio jQuery
uma solução pontual pode ser a seguinte...

```
var order = $("#meu_elemento").data("order");
var indice = +(order.split("-")[1]);
indice++;
$("#meu_elemento").data("order", "day-" + order);
```