# Como posso adicionar uma tagname(data-state) ao meu input hidden com o attr?

Tags: jquery

Não estou a conseguir adicionar um data attribute(data-state) como fiz com as restantes tag(value, type, name, etc) como mostro na imagem a seguir:

```
 $(".clicka").on("click", function () {
        $('#calendartable .tdfull').each(function (k) {
            if ($(this).data("id")) {
                $('<input/>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: 'disponibilidade[' + k + ']',
                    value: $(this).data("id"),
                    state: $(this).data("pending"),
                }).appendTo('form');
            }
            $('<input/>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'disponibilidade[' + k + '].titulo',
                value: $(this).data("start") + ' - ' + $(this).data("end"),
                state: $(this).data("pending"),
            }).appendTo('form');
            $('<input/>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'disponibilidade[' + k + '].inicio',
                value: $(this).data("start"),
                state: $(this).data("pending"),
            }).appendTo('form');
            $('<input/>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'disponibilidade[' + k + '].fim',
                value: $(this).data("end"),
                state: $(this).data("pending"),
            }).appendTo('form');
        });
```

Ele não reconhece o state, e penso que esteja a fazer algo de errado.
Queria por o estado em "pending". Existe algum evento que o faça? Pesquisei pelo deferred mas não percebi a ideia.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe uma attributo `state` nas normas de HTML como existe `value`, `name` e `type`, daí o jQuery guarda o que quer mas internamente.

Ou seja, [o que está a fazer vai funcionar](http://jsfiddle.net/g74jasr3/), mas sugiro que esses inputs sejam criados usando campos `data-`, ou seja: `data-state`.

Um exemplo seria:

```
        $('<input/>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            name: 'disponibilidade[' + k + '].fim',
            value: $(this).data("end"),
            'data-state': $(this).data("pending"),
        }).appendTo('form');
```

ou usando o método do jQuery: `.data()`:

```
        $('<input/>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            name: 'disponibilidade[' + k + '].fim',
            value: $(this).data("end")
        }).data('state', $(this).data("pending")).appendTo('form');
```

Para mais tarde ler esse valor pode usar os métodos `.attr('data-state')` ou `.data('state')`.

Repare que esses campos `data-` que o jQuery insere não são compativeis com JavaScript nativo, isso quer dizer que talvez não estejam visiveis no HTML apesar de estarem guardados e poderem ser lidos. **Mas** se tentar ir buscar via `getAttribute` não vai funcionar.

### Para fazer isso em JavaScript puro pode fazer com `setAttribute`.

Deixo um exemplo onde misturo JS nativo com jQuery para o código ficar mais curto, mas a parte do *getter* e *setter* dos campos *data* está só em JS nativo.

Exemplo:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('data-state', $(this).data("pending"));
$(input).attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'disponibilidade[' + k + '].fim',
    value: $(this).data("end")
}).appendTo('form');
```

**Exemplo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgZmBz**

Comment: Era isto mesmo que pretendia. Obrigado @Sergio :)

Comment: Não consigo fazendo as duas formas @Sergio.

O HTML aparece-me isto:

<input type="hidden" name="disponibilidade[3].fim" value="2015-02-27 15:00">

E tem de aparecer isto:

<input type="hidden" name="disponibilidade[3].fim" value="2015-02-27 15:00" data-state="pending">

Comment: @n1c0t0p uma coisa é o que vêz na consola outra coisa é se o valor foi gravado ou não. Testa isto na consola depois de inserir esses inputs: `$('[name^="disponibilidade"').map(function(){return $(this).data('state');})` o que dá?

Comment: dá vazio @Sergio

Comment: @n1c0t0p dá uma olhada aqui: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgZmBz - No HTML não aparece mas o valor é guardado.

Comment: então e como fazer com que apareca? Não tem muito sentido visto que o value e os outros aparecem, porque o date-state não?

Comment: @n1c0t0p é mesmo assim. Dê uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42038/129 - o jQuery guarda isso internamente. Para fazer isso "visivel" tem de usar javascript como nessa outra resposta.

Comment: Queria mesmo que este fosse visivel, só mesmo para conseguir perceber se está a executar bem o meu "post" que é outro passo que tenho.

Comment: @n1c0t0p juntei mais uma ideia na resposta para misturar JS e jQuery. Seria assim: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgZmBz

Comment: javascript é também uma boa hipótese.

Comment: @n1c0t0p consegui pôr a funcionar com o ultimo exemplo?

Comment: mesmo assim não. se tirar o data-state ele funciona e mete tudo como estava. Que sei que funciona. Agora, fazendo as 3 hipóteses que já me deu, não funciona de maneira nenhuma...

Comment: @n1c0t0p bem estranho isso. Pode colocar um link ou um jsFiddle para onde tem esse código? Viu que funciona nos exemplos que dei na resposta, acho que tem outros problemas no seu código. A ver se os descobrimos...

Comment: Bem aqui só está o javascript, porque isto tem API's e coisas do género, pis, é projeto da empresa.
No entanto, ele faz os clicks e envia os tais inputs, só que sem o date-state! http://jsfiddle.net/1weycmoo/

Comment: @n1c0t0p se juntares o HTML posso por isso a funcionar. 2 coisas que estão a falhar nesse fiddle: 1- O método jQuery `.on()` não existe ainda na versão 1.6, o 2- é erro meu deve ser `'data-state': $(this).data("pending")`, ou seja `'data-space'`com aspas pois chaves de objetos não podem ter  `-`

Comment: @n1c0t0p viste o comentário em cima ^ ?

Comment: sim vi, irei tentar, peço desculpa pela demora @Sergio

Answer (score 2):

Para adicionar um atributo pode fazer de duas formas diferentes.

1º utilizando `jQuery.attr()`

```
$('.elemento').attr('data-state', 'valor');
```

2º utilizando `jQuery.data()`

```
$('.elemento').data('state', 'valor');
```

Documentação [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Comment: Vê como fiz no input. Já tinha visto essa documentação, no entanto estava a tentar por no meu input. é possivel fazendo o meu $(this).data("state", "pending") ?

Comment: faça assim, onde esta state coloque 'data-state'

Comment: dessa maneira não dá, dá erro por causa do "-". tentei a segundo hipótese do @Sergio e também não está a funcionar.

O HTML aparece-me isto:

<input type="hidden" name="disponibilidade[3].fim" value="2015-02-27 15:00">

E tem de aparecer isto:

<input type="hidden" name="disponibilidade[3].fim" value="2015-02-27 15:00" data-state="pending">