# Comportamento estranho ao mostrar um atributo usando click();

Tags: jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um script que exige chamar um `click()` de um botão pois ele está invisível na página, no entanto o jQuery parece não retornar os atributos atualizados quando eles são alterados. Veja este exemplo:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.hidden').on('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).data('s'));
        alert($(this).data('s')); 
    });
});
    
$('.visivel').on('click', function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    $('.hidden').attr('data-s', s).click();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='visivel'>Clique me</button>
<button class='hidden' data-s='' style='display:none;'>Invisivel</button>
```

Como pode observar, ao testar é gerado um `alert()` informando os segundos atuais, mas se clicar novamente ele fica mostrando os segundos do primeiro clique, apesar do `data-s` ser alterado, o `alert` não retorna o novo segundo. Seria isso um bug do jQuery? Só consegui resolver usando `this.dataset.s` para que o `alert` funcione, gostaria de saber por que esse comportamento? E a estrutura é essa mesma, uma função dentro e outra fora do `$(function(){})`.

http://jsfiddle.net/6L3uxm93/

PS:

> A estrutura deve seguir a que eu coloquei como exemplo, uma das
>   funções deve estar fora do $(function(){}), isso porque a lógica do
>   projeto requer esse tipo de organização, estou usando outras
>   bibliotecas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O jQuery funciona de maneira imprevisível quando se mistura o setter/getter de `.attr('data-xx'` e `.data(`. Repara que o teu código funciona se usares [só `.attr()`](http://jsfiddle.net/9d50gczc/) ou [só `.data()`](http://jsfiddle.net/9d50gczc/1/).

Há outras perguntas que refere este problema ([esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50349/129) e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3504/129)). [O @bfavaretto descreveu bem o problema lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50349/129):

> A verificação dos atributos data- do HTML5 é na verdade um fallback. Se um valor for definido com .data(), recuperá-lo com esse mesmo método nem olha para o atributo (nem para a propriedade dataset do elemento em questão).

Ou seja, a primeira vez que corres o código o jQuery funciona como um *setter* e atribui o `data-` ao elemento. Depois não usa mais o mecanismo e quando procuras o valor com `.data()` "ele nem vê".

Comment: Agora sim entendi, na verdade o problema está em como o jQuery funciona ao lidar com atributos, sendo assim usarei apenas `data()` em ambos.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é o modo como você esta atualizando o `data-s`, utilize o método `data` e não `attr`

```
$(function(){
    $('.hidden').on('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).data('s'));
        alert($(this).data('s')); 
    });
});

$('.visivel').on('click', function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    $('.hidden').data('s', s).click();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use o atributo `.data()` do jQuery. Ele é o mais adequado para trabalhar com `data-attr` no HTML.

```
$(function(){
    $('.hidden').on('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).data('s'));
        alert($(this).data('s')); 
    });
});

$('.visivel').on('click', function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    $('.hidden').data('s', s).click();
});
```

Comment: Diego, como eu disse no final da pergunta, a estrutura deve seguir a que eu coloquei como exemplo, uma das funções deve estar fora do `$(function(){})`, isso porque a lógica do projeto requer esse tipo de organização, estou usando outras bibliotecas.

Comment: Editei meu post.