# Seletor jQuery eliminando zero incorretamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

No caso a seguir, possui um código sendo informado no atributo `data-produto` do meu input.

```js
$(".valor.partida").bind('blur', function(){
  alert($(this).data("produto"));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="valor partida" type="text" name="novo_valor_partida-1" value="11,11" data-produto="0101000" data-id="1">
```

O problema é que ao obter o valor desse atributo, ele retorna sem o zero inicial, apenas `101000`.

Por que isto ocorre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não confies no [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) do jQuery, ele não é de confiar :)

Neste caso da versão `1.4` [ele intepreta essa string como número](https://jsfiddle.net/jops79ou/)(!), porem isso foi corrigido em versões mais recentes [e já retorna string](https://jsfiddle.net/jops79ou/1/).

Usa JavaScript nativo:

```js
$(".valor.partida").bind('blur', function(){
     alert(this.dataset.produto);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="valor partida" type="text" name="novo_valor_partida-1" value="11,11" data-produto="0101000" data-id="1">
```

Numa [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78409/129) referí este problema, o [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) tem também [uma excelente explicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50355/129) sobre os processos internos do `.data()` do jQuery.

Comment: Desta forma está funcionando corretamente mas qual seria o problema com o `data`? Ele faz alguma conversão ou magia negra?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50349/jquery-n%c3%a3o-usa-o-dataset-do-html5-no-data

Comment: +1 @bfavaretto pelo esclarecimento

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade juntei á resposta. Ele trata como `Number`, isso foi contudo corrigido [nas versões posteriores](https://jsfiddle.net/jops79ou/1/).

Comment: Estava só esperando o time para aceitar tua resposta, @Sergio. Foi o suficiente para sanar as dúvidas.

Comment: @bfavaretto essa tua resposta é mto boa. Linkei. Não dá para upar duas vezes :P