# pegar o data-value com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando obter o valor do campo data de um select, mas não estou conseguindo. Somente o campo value padrão estou conseguindo obter.

O campo no select esta como: "data-valor2"

Utilizando .valor2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<select
  onchange="verificaHierarquia(this)" class="form-control"
  id="hierarquia" name="hierarquia.id">
  <option value="" data-valor=0 selected>SELECIONE...</option>
  <c:forEach var="hierarquia" items="${hierarquias }">
    <option value="${hierarquia.id }"
      data-valor2="${hierarquia.nivel }">${hierarquia.descricao }</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar o seu HTML na pergunta? Lembre-se que o site tem suporte para código fonte, basta utilizar o botão `{}` do editor.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss adicionado

Comment: Então o que você precisa é pegar o valor de `data-valor2` do elemento `<option>`, não do `<select>`?

Comment: O ideal seria o html renderizado, o que você quer dizer com data-value, você se refere ao data-valor2 ?

Comment: Sim o data-value é o data-valor2.

Comment: Fiz um teste apenas colocando " = valor2;" e funcionou irei testar outras situações.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tentei a solução desta pergunta, e não funcionou.

Comment: [Como alterar o valor de um atributo “data” em JQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3504/5878)

Comment: @sam já consegui resolver.

Só utilizei a variavel valor2 que já esta local

Comment: Blz! Sucesso aí.